# How secure is calling bitcoind JSON-RPC from same computer?

Tags: bitcoind, security, json-rpc

I am wondering if calling JSON-RPC from the computer it is running on is secure. I read [How secure is calling bitcoind JSON-RPC?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/how-secure-is-calling-bitcoind-json-rpc) and understand why it is insecure to do so from a different computer.

Is there a secure way to call it from the same computer **without** using [SSL?](http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon%20p)

Comment: It's secure in principle. Just make sure that if your doing this on a computer connected to the internet that all relevant ports are closed. Also there is not all the much of a point in using ssl on localhost, it will just add latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By default, Bitcoin will only listen for RPC connections on local loopback. Local loopback cannot be accessed or spied upon by another computer.